# How to remove Windows' Driver Verifier from Ubuntu in a Windows-Linux Dual Boot system

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot, bsod, microsoft-driver-verifier

I have a dual-boot desktop computer with Ubuntu + Windows 11. I foolishly played around with Window's Driver Verifier feature, and when I restarted Windows, it went into an endless cycle of Blue Screen of Death saying:

> DRIVER_VERIFIER_DETECTED_VIOLATION

In some instances, it would load to the Repair screen. I tried to Repair but it failed.

I also tried to press F8 and Shift-F8 repeatedly after choosing the Windows partition but the BSOD came up anyways. I read online that modern computers don't offer the choice of pressing F8 for safe mode anymore...is it true?

So I boot into Ubuntu and look into ways to disable Driver Verifier from there.

First, I tried to open the system32 folder in the Windows partition to delete the driver verifier .exe file, but I got the error:

> This location could not be displayed...input/output error

I tried to unmount then remount the Windows partition using this command:

> sudo mount -t ntfs -3g -o rw /dev/sda3 /media.windows

But I got error

> Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened

I tried to repair the Windows partition from Ubuntu, but got error message that Windows is in an unclean stage...

Any ideas what I can do next?

Comment: Windows, since v. 8.x and ~2012, has a Fast Startup "feature" that keeps its partitions semi-hibernated thus preventing access from outside like you tried to do. That's why we say disabling that "feature" is a must when dual-booting. That said, in this case it saved you from yourself. The reason for disabling it in a dual-boot is to have normal access to DATA (i.e. NON-system) partitions for shared files, NOT (NEVER!) to touch the Windows system partition like you intended. NEVER do that and that's NOT a solution anyway.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0xc4--driver-verifier-detected-violation and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/driver-verifier Very likely you need to boot Windows installation media and disable it from the recovery environment. I'm just an occasional Windows user so not answering this one.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to disable Driver Verifier when booting
Windows in Safe Mode.

See the article
[Start your PC in safe mode in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode-in-windows-92c27cff-db89-8644-1ce4-b3e5e56fe234#WindowsVersion=Windows_11)
for the details, but in short you abort Windows startup three
times using the power button, then get into
*Troubleshoot > Advanced options > Startup Settings > Restart*.

As noted in the comments, for dual-boot you need to
[disable Fast Startup](https://www.guidingtech.com/disable-fast-startup-on-windows-11/).